# ConcurrentHashMap updated by a Spark UDF are not synchronised

Tags: multithreading, scala, unit-testing, apache-spark

I'm trying to unit test some logic by creating a mock class.
The mocked class is injected with a hashmap to use as the persistence storage.
A `Spark` UDF, `my_udf` is called during the test and it is supposed to update the value in this mock storage.

I've setup the test as below with some test data.

```
   val jobId = "TestJobId"
   val name = "abcd" <- used to as a key to store a count in the storage
 
   val session = initSparkSession() <-- create a spark session with 'test_view'

   val config = Config(Some(IncrementalLoadConfig(Map(name -> 1), jobId)))

    @volatile <- tried without this as well
    var versionStorage: ConcurrentHashMap[String, ConcurrentHashMap[String, Long]] = new ConcurrentHashMap()
    config.incrementalLoading.foreach { i =>
      @volatile
      val c = new ConcurrentHashMap[String, Long]()
      i.versions.foreach { case (k, v) => c.put(k, v) }
      versionStorage.put(i.jobId, c)
    }
```

And pass it to the mock class and register UDFs

```
val mock = new MockClass(configs, versionStorage) 
mock.registerUDFs(session) <-- spark session as param
```

Then fetch some data from the `test_view` which also calls the `my_udf`

```
val rows = session.sql(s"""select * from test_view where my_udf("$name")""").collect()
```

Then I check the `versionStorage` to make some assertions.

```
rows.length should be(2)
versionStorage.get(jobId).get(name) should be(3L)
```

When I try to assert, the `versionStorage` consists the old values that got initialised before calling `session.sql`.
I debugged and verified that the `versionStorage` is updated during the `my_udf` function call. But that updates are not reflected in to the unit test.

It appears to be an issue related to using multiple threads.
I also tried using `volatile` & `AtomicLong`s but couldn't find a solution for the issue.

I would appreciate any help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to achieve? Spark runs, by design, on multiple nodes and thus each node will get a "different" ConcurrentHashMap. Actually I'm surprised this evens runs at all but maybe I missed something..

Comment: @GaëlJ `my_udf("$name")` saves the largest value of the `version` column in the spark dataframe into a db, as a key value pair `$name -> versionNumber`. Creating `ConcurrentHashMap` is done before running the spark code. It is only referenced inside the UDF `my_udf` as an alternative to the actual database that is used to store the key,value pairs that I mentioned.

Comment: Why do that in a UDF? Run a query that gives you the data you need (max version by name), then store it in your database/map.

Comment: @GaëlJ It's not that simple. This works fine in production. Just the mock is not working.